# Почему «отсрачивать» неправильно?

Tags: орфография, правила, чередования

Существуют пары глаголов совершенного и несовершенного вида с буквой ***о*** в корне, в которых в несовершенном виде корневая ***о*** меняется на ***а*** под ударением. Например:

вытолкать - выталкивать,
засолить - засаливать,
заморозить - замораживать,
скосить - скашивать,
прострочить - прострачивать и т. д.

Почему логично напрашивающаяся (тоже пример) пара к *отсрочить* не *отср**а**чивать*, а *отср**о**чивать*?

И как называется это явление? В примерах чередующихся гласных этих корней я не нахожу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://rusgram.narod.ru/836-849.html#845

> (АКАДЕМИЯ НАУК СССР ИНСТИТУТ РУССКОГО ЯЗЫКА РУССКАЯ ГРАММАТИКАб 1980,
> § 845) Наличие или отсутствие чередования |о - а| в глаголах с морфом
> -ива- связано с характером ударения мотивирующего глагола... Если мотивирующий глагол имеет ударение на корневой фонеме |о|, то
> чередование |о - а| имеет место *лишь в части глаголов* с морфом
> -ива-: *заготовить - заготавливать, закончить - заканчивать, заморозить - замораживать, отработать - отрабатывать,* **но** *проспорить -
> просп**о**ривать, размусолить - размус**о**ливать (прост.), рассредоточить - рассред**о**точивать, упрочить - упр**о**чивать*

Я привел фрагмент, касающийся глаголов с -ива- и ударением на корневой фонеме, как в нашем случае (отсрочивать/отсрочить). Как видно, нет общего правила, гарантирующего корректность альтернативного варианта с -а-. На "Грамоте" со ссылкой на этот же материал приводят ваше слово как недопустимый вариант.
http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C

**P. S.** На мой взгляд, этот альтернативный вариант достаточно исключить из рассмотрения как *неблагозвучный*.